# Some values in this array are turning to zero (0) for no particular reason

Tags: c++, arrays, function, zero

I take an input for an array, then run a *completely unrelated function*. Somehow, the values of the array are different after this point.
As far as I can tell, the first few values become zero (0).

Here is the opening segment of the main function:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, n;
    Nod* root=NULL;    //Nod class user defined elsewhere
    cin>>n;
    int A[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
      {
          cin>>A[i];
          cout<<A[i]<<"\t";//TESTER
      }
    cout<<endl<<endl;
    Nod no[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       no[i].nowhere(n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
       cout<<A[i]<<"\t";//TESTER
    cout<<endl<<endl;

    ...//rest of main()
    ...
}
```

Here is the class Nod with the nowhere() function:

```
class Nod
{
    public: Nod* parent;
    Nod* child[];

    void nowhere(int n)
        {
            parent=NULL;
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
                child[i]=NULL;
        }
};
```

Here is a sample input and output:

*Input*:

```
5
4 -1 4 1 1
```

*Output*:

```
4    -1    4    1    1
0     0    4    1    1
```

As far as I can see, the `nowhere()` function should not affect the array `A[`] at all. Then, how are the values changing?

Comment: You need a [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). You cannot learn by guessing and looking at code snippets on the interwebs. `Nod* child[];` is not doing what you imagine it's doing. It's not legal C++ at all. Nor is `cin>>n; int A[n];`.

Comment: If you are using g++ or clang, these flags are *mandatory*: `-std=c++17 -Wall -Werror -pedantic`. (You may have to use some lower number if your gcc is too old; see the documentation for your release).

Comment: also use of VLA is bad idea anyway

Answer (score 4):

Function `nowhere` causes undefined behavior by writing past the end of `child[]` array. The array has zero elements in your scenario, so accessing any index causes undefined behavior.

Since you are allocating `Nod`s in an array, you should change `child[]` to `std::vector<Nod*> child`, and initialize it to an appropriate size dynamically as needed:

```
std::vector<Nod*> child;

void nowhere(int n) {
    parent = NULL;
    child = std::vector<Nod*>(n, NULL);
}
```

**Note:** Consider restructuring your code to not use "raw" pointers, or vectors of pointers. Switch to smart pointers, or use objects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem:**

You're getting zeros all over the first two cells of `int A[n]` as the result of ***undefined behavior*** caused by `nowhere(int n)` overwriting some of the contents of `A[n]`. The following loop does so:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   child[i]=NULL;
```

The problem is that `child` is not being allocated before the iterated assignments of its cells to the value of `NULL`, and so you effectively write `NULL` (numerical value of `0`) to an unexpected place in the memory. This is called an [Overflow/Overrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). In your case the program overruns the address of where `child` resides, in a way that gets you zeroes all the way onto the content of `int A[n]`.

**The solution:**

Use correct C++ to define `child`, like this:

```
std::vector<Nod*> child;
```

then, rewrite `nowhere(int n)` like this:

```
void nowhere(int n)
{
    parent=NULL;
    child.resize(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        child[i]=NULL;
}
```

**BTW:**

1. You can forgo the entire looping in `nowhere(int n)` and this one liner does the `resize()` for you and fills the values like you wanted:

   `child = std::vector<Nod*>(n, NULL);`
2. `Nod* child[];` is quite likely not doing what you intended for it. The C++ syntax for C-style arrays of raw pointers would in this case be either:

   - `Nod** child;` if you're later allocating it dynamically like this `child = new Nod*[n]` (but don't forget to later free this memory with `delete[] child`)

   or

   - `Nod* child[n];` if `n` is a constant expression -- which is not the case here anyways as you are receiving `n` as input.